# Can I know which byte range to read from a remote mp4 file for FFMpeg to decode a keyframe?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I need to decode a of keyframe of a video file (mp4, h264 encoded). I know the timestamp of the keyframe I want to extract/decode. I want to minimize amount of data being read in memory. For this, I need to know beforehand exactly the minimal byte range I would require that encompasses this keyframe. How do I know what is the minimal byte range in the whole mp4 byte stream I need to read in order to be able to decode the keyframe?

I currently find the appropriate keyframe in the `index_entries` contained in the header. I get its byte position (`pos` attribute) and timestamp (`timestamp` attribute). I calculate the range as follows:

`startBytes`: minimum of:

1. the `pos` of the keyframe
2. the `pos` of the nearest index entry in the audio stream happening at or before the keyframe's timestamp.

This way when it's decoding the frame, if it also needs the audio content for demuxing, it would have it.

`endBytes`: maximum of:

1. the `pos` of the next frame in the video stream's index, after the keyframe
2. the `pos` of the next frame in the audio stream's index after the timestamp of the wished keyframe.

This way I know that I have everything up until the next frame in the index, which **theoretically should be enough to decode the keyframe only.**

I then read the appropriate byte range.

When I try to decode the frame, I run in a loop until I succeed:

- `avcodec_read_frame`
- `avcodec_send_packet`
- `avcodec_receive_frame`

I ignore `AVERROR(EAGAIN)` errors.

`avcodec_receive_frame` fails multiple times with error `AVERROR(EAGAIN)` which I ignore, until it fails saying that the memory it wants to read isn't available (wants to read after `endBytes`). I explicitly tell it to fail if it wants to read more than it has already read.

Note: for other keyframes at other positions in other videos, it sometimes succeeds (probably because the range is big enough by chance), but it fails more often than not.

**My question is:** Why is the end of the range not enough to be able to decode only the one keyframe? Is there any way to more precisely calculate the exact range in bytes I would need in order to decode a particular keyframe?